# Single line input multiple values used space 4 5 without press enter

Tags: r, input, user-input

How can I input two digits in a single line using space like `5 6`?

c code:

```
int a=0,b=0;
printf(" Input a and b in digits: \'use space\' ");
scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
```

R single line input multiple values used space 4 5 without press enter:

```
sum_of_total_number <- function (first,second){
  first <-  as.numeric(first)
  second <-  as.numeric(second)
  return (first + second )
}

main <- function(a,b){
  { a <- readline("Input value a: "); b <- readline("INput value b: ")}
  print(sum_of_total_number(a,b))
}

main()
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean?! do you mean `("4 5")`

Comment: Take any two digits user input in a single line and separate by space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `scan()` function to read multiple values.

```
main <- function(){
  vals <- scan(n=2, what=numeric(), quiet=TRUE)
  print(sum(vals))
}
main()
```